# Почему RedBean считается плохим?

Tags: php, orm, redbeanphp

Я решил изучить `ORM`, мой выбор пал на **RedBean**, во время обучения я узнал, что многие плохо относятся к **RedBean**. Узнал в интернете, что лучше изучать **Doctrine ORM** или **Eloquent**
В чём заключается проблема RedBean? Сейчас уже есть версия 5.4.2, возможно в этой версии исправили проблемы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никого не слушайте. Для того, чтобы сделать выводы - необходимо самостоятельно поработать с библиотекой. 
RedBean - очень неплохая вещь. Она немного проще, чем приведённые Вами примеры, но это тоже можно посчитать её плюсом. 
Она в разы упрощает работу с БД, да и весь синтаксис написания достаточно прост. Раньше были проблемы с дополнительными запросами но, на сколько мне известно, они давно все решены.

Я долгое время пользовался данной ORM, и прям плохого ничего не могу сказать, за исключением какого-нибудь случая создания нужной таблицы. Или раньше была проблема в работе с большими данными типа blob
RedBean сам создаёт и модифицирует формат таблицы, в зависимости от типа данных, что не всегда удобно.

В остальном же прекрасная ORM для просто и быстрой работы с БД. 
*Однако, если Вы начинающий пользователь баз данных, то приоритетным вариантом будет изучить сначала строение, например, sql и основные её параметры, прежде, чем переходить на RedBean.*

Иначе в процессе работы могут возникнуть ситуации непонимания самой работы с базами данных, так как readbean избавляет от необходимости строить запросы в формате синтаксиса sql. 
Так что пользуйтесь и никого не слушайте )

Answer (score 2):

**Doctrine** и **Eloquent** более MVC направленные.

**ReadBean** же как бы глобально предоставляет доступ к базе данных

Comment: А в чем MVC направленность заключается? Eloquent и ReadBean это Active Record. Doctrine это DataMapper. Что значит ReadBean глобально предоставляетдоступ к бд?

Comment: @ДенисНестерюк причем здесь архитектура? Речь о взаимодействии

Comment: Просто стало интересно, что вы имеете ввиду под mvc направленностью? Я недавно начал использовать doctrine и не заметил этой самой mvc направленности.

Comment: @ДенисНестерюк mvc ооп, разделение доступа

Comment: В общем так и не понял я из набора слов, как вы связали mvc и orm.

Comment: @ДенисНестерюк в readbean нет разделения доступа, так думаю понятней)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102860/discussion-between-slava-and--).